# If two slopes of lines crossing the origin are the same, how are the arguments of the corresponding complex numbers related?

Tags: complex-analysis

For two complex numbers  $z_1=x_1+iy_1$ and $z_2=x_2+iy_2$ obeying
$$
\frac{y_1}{x_1}=\frac{y_2}{x_2},
$$
how does one show that
$$\textrm{arg}(z_1)=\textrm{arg}(z_2)+n\pi ?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ are the arguments of $z_1$ and $z_2$, then $\tan\theta_1=\frac{y_1}{x_1}$ and $\tan\theta_2=\frac{y_2}{x_2}$

$$\tan\theta_1=\tan\theta_2$$

$$\frac{\sin\theta_1}{\cos\theta_1}=\frac{\sin\theta_2}{\cos\theta_2}$$

$$\sin\theta_1\cos\theta_2=\sin\theta_2\cos\theta_1$$

$$\sin\theta_1\cos\theta_2-\sin\theta_2\cos\theta_1=0$$

$$\sin(\theta_1-\theta_2)=0$$

$$\theta_1-\theta_2=n\pi$$

Comment: If both $x_1>0$ and  $x_2>0$, I think that we should have $\theta_1-\theta_2=2n\pi$. But how does one show this?

Comment: If both $x_1>0$ and $x_2>0$, then both $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ belong to quadrant I or IV, so it is impossible to have $\theta_1-\theta_2=(2k+1)\pi$ for an integer $k$